# php parse JSON mixture of object hierarchies and arrays to read values

Tags: php, arrays, json, rest

Need to read out values from array 'places'-> then values from array 'parents' 
from response ($response) i receive with REST API:
then decode with `$json = json_decode($response, true);`

```
Array
(
    [status_code] => 200
    [data] => Array
        (
            [places] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 11878
                            [name] => Times Square
                            [name_suffix] => Manhattan, New York City, USA
                            [parents] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 32280039
                                            [name] => Theater District
                                            [level] => neighbourhood
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => poi:28010161
                                            [name] => Manhattan Community Board 5
                                            [level] => region
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => region:1981637
                                            [name] => Manhattan Island
                                            [level] => island
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => poi:28043160
                                            [name] => Manhattan
                                            [level] => neighbourhood
                                        )
                                )

                            [perex] => Times Square (nicknamed “The Crossroads of the World”) is the best known square in New York City and also its beating heart.
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 11874
                            [name] => Empire State Building
                            [name_suffix] => Manhattan, New York City, USA
                            [parents] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => poi:32108808
                                            [name] => Midtown South
                                            [level] => neighbourhood
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => poi:28010161
                                            [name] => Manhattan Community Board 5
                                            [level] => region
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => region:1981637
                                            [name] => Manhattan Island
                                            [level] => island
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => region:46071
                                            [name] => Manhattan
                                            [level] => neighbourhood
                                        )

                                )

                            [perex] => An iconic Art Deco skyscraper and one of the best known buildings in New York. It got its name from the city’s nickname the "Empire State".
                        )
                )

        )
)
```

I am struggling to loop trough objects, which are unknown at time of request and not always same or available for each separate request

```
foreach ($json->data as $places_list) {
    foreach ($places_list->places as $placesItem) {
        foreach($placesItem->(HELP HERE) as $place_detail) {
               echo json_encode($place_detail) . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Could you kindly help to achieve a generic function, which will allow to go (a) to 'places' level, then (b) to retrieve values from 'parents'

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't match the data output as it uses object notation.  But anyway, it's just a matter of getting the right hierarchy of the data.

This code goes through a list of the `places` array and echo's the name from there.  Then an inner loop goes through the `parents` elements and outputs the name from there

```
foreach ($json['data']['places'] as $places_list) {
    echo $places_list['name']."-";
    foreach ($places_list['parents'] as $parents) {
        echo $parents['name'] ."/";
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

which outputs

```
Times Square-Theater District/Manhattan Community Board 5/Manhattan Island/Manhattan/
Empire State Building-Midtown South/Manhattan Community Board 5/Manhattan Island/Manhattan/
```

Comment: Thank you! Of course i missed that one, with object notation..your function is beautiful, working as expected. Have a great Christmas time

Answer (score 0):

We are working on a generic solution with a recursion function.
json is a mix of arrays and objects which make it very hard to import even for ICT professionals. check out with me later via DM , it should be ready by march 2023.